# Using Artisan::call() to run package migrations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I need to migrate my database schema for some unit tests I'm writing, and one of these migrations is included in a package. Normally, from the command line, I'd run this command:

```
php artisan migrate --package=tappleby/laravel-auth-token
```

And to run my own migrations in code I'd do:

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

However, I can't seem to get Artisan to run package migrations from inside code. I've tried this:

```
Artisan::call('migrate --package=tappleby/laravel-auth-token');
```

but that results in an unknown command error. I've also tried these:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', '--package=tappleby/laravel-auth-token');
Artisan::call('migrate', ['--package=tappleby/laravel-auth-token']);
Artisan::call('migrate', ['package=tappleby/laravel-auth-token']);
```

None of the above works. What's the correct way of running package migrations in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax uses an associative array for the command parameters, where the item key is the name of the parameter and the item value is the value of the parameter. This should work in your case:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', ['--package' => 'tappleby/laravel-auth-token']);
```

Comment: It's either that or a simple array of arguments like `Artisan::call('migrate', ['--package', 'tappleby/laravel-auth-token']);`

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `--path`:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => 'vendor/systeminc/laravel-admin/src/database/migrations']);
```